# How to specify in Gradle an `@OutputDirectory` for an `Exec` task?

Tags: gradle

I have the following:

```
task cloneProtobuf(type: Exec) {
  workingDir "${rootProject.buildDir}/github.com/google"
  commandLine 'git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/google/protobuf.git'

  enabled = { -> !new File(workingDir, "protobuf/.git").isDirectory() }()
  doFirst {
    mkdir workingDir
  }
}
```

Rather than explicitly setting `enabled` and having gradle indicate that the task was `SKIPPED`, I would rather have gradle consider that if the `protobuf` directory already exists, the task is `UP-TO-DATE`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of enable/disable a task, please register a task [output](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs), then gradle will be aware itself if a task is up-to-date or not. Please have a look at the example below which you can find helpful:

```
task mk(type: Exec) {
  def output = project.file('mk')
  outputs.dir output
  commandLine 'mkdir', output
  workingDir '.'
}
```

If you run `gradle mk` twice, the task will execute only once.

Comment: This works for a bit then the build starts emitting errors. I'm guessing it's because the timestamp of the directory changes if its contents are changed (eg files are created or removed in the directory).

Comment: Hmm, even if I specify `outputs.file project.file("${workingDir}/protobuf/.git/config")`, it's still failing.

Comment: @NoelYap could you please provide an example that reproduces the error you're getting?

Comment: ```
task cloneProtobuf(type:Exec) {
  workingDir protobufDir.getParentFile()
  commandLine 'git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/google/protobuf.git'
  outputs.file project.file("build/github.com/google/protobuf/.git/config")
  doFirst {
    mkdir workingDir
  }
}
task checkoutProtobuf(type:Exec) {
  workingDir protobufDir
  commandLine 'git', 'checkout', "v${protocVersion()}"
  dependsOn cloneProtobuf
}
task autogenProtobuf(type:Exec) {
  workingDir protobufDir
  executable './autogen.sh'
  outputs.file project.file("$workingDir/configure")
  dependsOn checkoutProtobuf
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the formatting. Don't know how to get SO to format properly code in comments.

Comment: @NoelYap, sure. Will have a look.

Comment: @NoelYap the following task clones the repo correctly: https://gist.github.com/Opalo/45e6e6208a0889202a6bd80c436a510d, you must be doing something wrong, check the paths once again - you can verify them with `println`. Also to need to use `project.file` for `outputs` - pass there a `String`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142212/discussion-between-noel-yap-and-opal).